# Donald Duck almost burns down his house trying to bake something

Tags: story-identification, disney, donald-duck

I'm looking for a comic book on Donald Duck.

The general plot is that Donald wants to bake something (I think it had chocolate in it?), it's like a gift for Valentine's or something similar. But, because he his baking multiple quantities (4x) of the same thing, he quadruples quantities, time and temperature on his oven. His house nearly burns down, everything is ruined, and the firemen warn him to only change the quantity and time, not temperature of the oven.

I'm currently scouring through Carl Barks and Don Rosa's chapters, but so far, without luck. Can anyone point out the name/author/year of this comic story?

Comment: Is this science fiction or fantasy? Donald Duck?

Comment: @JohnRennie [per Meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11530/98028), it'd seem Donald Duck is on-topic. (meh)

Comment: Definetely on-topic, we have plenty of similar questions. On the other hand, I guess downvoters can easily demonstrate that Donald Duck and alikes have nothing to do with sci-fi or fantasy just pointing at real occurrences of cities on Earth inhabited by human sized talking ducks, dogs, cats, mouses, etc.

Comment: Still got to ask, any idea of the years you're the most likely to have read it? (I know you mentioned Barks and Don Rosa, bu there are so many Donald Duck writers...) Also, that was in English, right? (though I'd guess so, with you mentioning the two above)

Comment: @Jenayah I read this in Portuguese, around the 2000's. Portuguese publishers aggregate stories and publish them in large volumes. I know I've read a few from Rosa and Banks because I've recognized them. I've also read some from Uncle Scrooge, Gyro, Carioca, Magma, etc. It was in color, and probably translated from English, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was asking because I _think_ a lot of Donald Duck comics are the local writers' inventions. :)